# Error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to in

Tags: java

I'm trying to print the start value with the conversion but I'm getting this error:

```
error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int
        int zeile = Programm.printTable(10.0, 1000.0, 50);
```

This is my code

```java
public class miles {
    
    public static double km2meilen(double entfernung) {
        return (entfernung / 1.852);
    }

    public static double meilen2km(double entfernung) {
        return ((double) entfernung * 1.852);
    }

    public static double printTable(double start, double end, double step) {
        System.out.printf("\n km Seemeilen Seemeilen km");
        double y = 0.0;
        for (; start <= end; start += end) {
            double x = 0.0;
            System.out.printf("\n%10.2f %10.2f %10.2f %10.2f", (double) start, (double) km2meilen(start), (double) start, (double) meilen2km(start));
            x = x + 1.0;
            return x;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printTable(0.0, 50.0, 1000.0);
    }
}
```

Comment: the error line isn't in the code so ?

Answer (score 0):

The `printTable` method returns a `double` so you may save it in a double, or explicitly cast it

```
double zeile = Programm.printTable(10.0, 1000.0, 50);

int zeile = (int) Programm.printTable(10.0, 1000.0, 50);
```

---

Then, your conversion methods don't need any cast

```
public static double km2meilen(double entfernung) {
    return entfernung / 1.852;
}
public static double meilen2km(double entfernung) {
    return entfernung * 1.852;
}
```

And your `printTable` doesn't define `x` where it should, and doesn't return it where it should, and has useless casting too

```
public static double printTable(double start, double end, double step) {
    System.out.printf("\n%10s %10s %10s %10s", "km", "Seemeilen", "Seemeilen", "km");
    double y = 0.0;
    double x = 0.0;
    for (; start <= end; start += step) {
        System.out.printf("\n%10.2f %10.2f %10.2f %10.2f", start, km2meilen(start), start, meilen2km(start));
        x = x + 1.0;
    }
    return x;
}
```

```
        km  Seemeilen  Seemeilen         km
     10,00       5,40      10,00      18,52
     60,00      32,40      60,00     111,12
    110,00      59,40     110,00     203,72
    160,00      86,39     160,00     296,32
    210,00     113,39     210,00     388,92
    260,00     140,39     260,00     481,52
    310,00     167,39     310,00     574,12
    360,00     194,38     360,00     666,72
    410,00     221,38     410,00     759,32
    460,00     248,38     460,00     851,92
    510,00     275,38     510,00     944,52
    560,00     302,38     560,00    1037,12
    610,00     329,37     610,00    1129,72
    660,00     356,37     660,00    1222,32
    710,00     383,37     710,00    1314,92
    760,00     410,37     760,00    1407,52
    810,00     437,37     810,00    1500,12
    860,00     464,36     860,00    1592,72
    910,00     491,36     910,00    1685,32
    960,00     518,36     960,00    1777,92
```

Comment: Fixed it thanks guys, the issue was that the Table did return void not a int as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Conversion might be issue, you can type case it as mentioned below , moreover, `printTable` is giving compilation error, you might need to put `return`  outside of for loop.

```
int zeile = (int)Programm.printTable(10.0, 1000.0, 50);
```